# Save HTML in GeckoFx VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

I am trying to save the whole html code of the active page within the GeckoFX Webbrowser in VB.NET.

Does anyone know how to do this? Is it possible at all?

Here is what I've tried:

```
gwb_Browser.Navigate(sURL)
gwb_Browser.SaveDocument()
```

I got back an empty HTML-Document.

Then I tried:

```
gwb_Browser.Navigate("view-source:" + sURL)
```

Now the HTML-Code of the site was displayed in my Browser.
I tried to select the complete document and save it.

```
gwb_Browser.SelectAll()
gwb_Browser.SaveDocument()
```

But the result was the same empty HTML file as before.

So far this is everything I could think of.

Is there another way I did not try?

EDIT:
@Tom:
When trying your suggestion the content of my String looks like this:
    "< html >< head >< /head >< body >< /body >< /html >"
_

While using the standard webbrowser control, my code to save the HTML code looks like this:

```
Dim hReq As HttpWebRequest
Dim hRes As HttpWebResponse
Dim sSessionPage As String
Dim oStream As Stream
Dim oStreamReader As StreamReader

hReq = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(sURL), HttpWebRequest)
hRes = DirectCast(hReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

oStream = hRes.GetResponseStream()
oStreamReader = New StreamReader(oStream)

sSessionPage = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
```

I can't find any equivalent in the geckofx browser.

Comment: Please make an attempt, and provide what you have tried.

Comment: Use something like: str = gwb_Browser.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml; Then save str to a file.

Comment: Edited my initial question